# How NLU preprocessing data module work

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu

I am having a problem with NLU of Rasa. I don't understand how NLU preprocessing data module works so I need yours help. Please tell me some information or document about Rasa because the document of rasa so very few. Thanks all.

Comment: Hi Tam, could you clarify what you mean by "preprocessing data module"? I think it might be easier for people to answer your question effectively if it's a little more specific

Comment: Check out this 4 part series - https://medium.com/series/nlp-behind-chatbots-demystifying-rasanlu-318a8adb39ed